# Restore database from *.frm files - mysql?

Tags: database, database-restore

unfortunally Windows crashed yesterday, and I only have the time to retrive the frm files from my mysql database. I've had a look on Google and have found that this is just the table structure (Which is exactly what I'm after)

So, is there a way I can restore these files back into mysql. I've placed them in the directory where I took them from yesterday, and phpmyadmin recognize's the database, but it doesn't decect the tables, but I can't create tables using the same name either.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting you should stop the WAMP services, or at least restart the services when prompted to start them.

On the old server instance navigate to the MySQL data folder by default this should look something similar to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\data\ where mysql5.1.53 will be the version number of the previously installed MySQL database.

Inside this folder you should see a few files and folders. The folders are the actual MySQL databases, and contain a bunch of .frm files which we will require. You should recognise the folder names as the database names. These folder and all their contents can be copied directly to your MySQL data folder, you can neglect the default databases mysql, performance_schema, test.

If you started the server now you will see the databases are picked up, however the databases will contain none of the tables which were copied across. In order for the contents of the database to be picked up, back in the data folder you should see a file ibdata1, this is the data file for tables, copy this directly into the data folder, you should already have a file in your new data folder called “ibdata1″ so you may wish to rename this to ibdata1.bak before copying across the ibdata1 from the old MySQL data folder.

Once this has been done Restart all the WAMP services. You can use PhpMyAdmin to check if your databases have been successfully restored.